# java is listening from :::0 Causing firewall dialog that appears then disappears

Tags: macos, firewall, osx-mountain-lion

Every 3 hours or so on my mac, a firewall dialog appears and disappears almost instantly. It lasts long enough to be annoying, but not long enough to read it. When it happens, I check `appfirewall.log` and there is always a `java is listening from :::0` message right about when it happens. I installed Little Snitch and it didn't change anything. Does anyone know how to stop or workaround this? Even something like causing the window to pop up under my active window would be fine, then it wouldn't annoy me.

Comment: Have you read any of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+is+listening+from+%3A%3A%3A0)?

Comment: Yes, all of them. None have an answer.

Comment: OK, mentioning some of the things you tried apart from "I installed little snitch and it made no difference" might help narrow things down. Also, what Java programs are you likely to be running?

Comment: I've tried turning the firewall off and that works but ins't what I want to do. Aside from that, there isn't much I can think of, especially since I don't know what program is causing the problem. I do android development so I have Eclipse and the ADK installed, but neither were running at the time the problem occurred. Other than that, I don't know what uses Java and what doesn't.

Comment: maybe try running a screen recorder and catching the error, you could run it from e.g.  2h:50min-3h:10min  after the last one, so it covers the time when you predict it will appear, or you could run it longer to catch it

Comment: how about http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90920/firewall-window-pops-up-then-vanishes